# unable to install meanjs on linux mint

Tags: node.js, mean-stack, meanjs

it has been one week now that i was trying to install meanjs stack and had no success.

Everytime I follow some tutorial and get errors. Now I end up with many issues, too much nodejs version, i dont know which one should be with what and why do karma not working ...etc
is there anyway to remove everything and install meanjs correctly and get it running successfully

```
+ WARNING: It is strongly recommended that you change sessionSecret config while running in production!
  Please add `sessionSecret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET || 'super amazing secret'` to 
  `config/env/production.js` or `config/env/local.js`


/opt/mean/node_modules/connect-mongo/src/index.js:3
const Promise = require('bluebird');
^^^^^
error: uncaughtException: Use of const in strict mode. date=Mon Jul 18 2016 19:15:59 GMT+0400 (GST), pid=29602, uid=1000, gid=1000, cwd=/opt/mean, execPath=/usr/local/bin/node, version=v0.10.33, argv=[node, /opt/mean/server], rss=47960064, heapTotal=35267072, heapUsed=18951416, loadavg=[0.5966796875, 0.453125, 0.66748046875], uptime=4058.491096953
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object. (/opt/mean/node_modules/connect-mongo/index.js:1:80)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object. (/opt/mean/config/lib/express.js:12:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
```

**below is my system config**

- Linux Mint 17.2 64-bit
- NodeJS v0.10.33
- npm 1.4.28
- bower 1.7.9
- mongodb v3.0.12

Can anyone please help me, I want to get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't dug into it, but I'm guessing the version of node you have doesn't support the 'const' keyword.  0.10.x is a (fairly) old version of node; have you considered upgrading to one of the versions that has ES 6 native support?